# Excel VBA Ribbon resets after making manual changes

Tags: excel, vba, ribbon

I made a customized ribbon via VBA, the ribbon itself is working fine until I manually change something in the ribbon. When I change something all the buttons I created with VBA are gone.

How can I stop that from happening?

This is my code to setup the ribbon:

```
Sub SetupRibbonEmp()

Dim hFile As Long
Dim path As String, fileName As String, ribbonXML As String, user As String

hFile = FreeFile
user = Environ("Username")
path = "C:\Users\" & user & "\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\"
fileName = "Excel.officeUI"

ribbonXML = "<mso:customUI      xmlns:mso='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui'>" &                 vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "  <mso:ribbon>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "    <mso:qat/>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "    <mso:tabs>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "      <mso:tab id='Planning' label='Planning'  insertAfterMso='TabHome'>" &         vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "        <mso:group id='Algemeen' label='Algemeen' autoScale='true'>" &     vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "          <mso:button id='BureauplanningOpenen' label='Bureauplanning openen' " & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "imageMso='FormulaMoreFunctionsMenu'      onAction='OpenBureauplanning'/>" & vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "          <mso:button id='CapaciteitsplanningOpenen' label='Capacitietsplanning openen' " & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "imageMso='AddressBook'      onAction='OpenCapaciteitsplanning'/>" & vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "          <mso:button id='ProjectplanningOpenen' label='Projectplanning openen' " & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "imageMso='NewNotebookShort'      onAction='OpenProjectplanning'/>" & vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "          <mso:button id='PersoonlijkePlanningOpenen' label='Medewerkersplanning openen' " & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "imageMso='CondolatoryEvent'      onAction='OpenMedewerkersplanning'/>" & vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "        </mso:group>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "      </mso:tab>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "    </mso:tabs>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "  </mso:ribbon>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "</mso:customUI>"

ribbonXML = Replace(ribbonXML, """", "")

Open path & fileName For Output Access Write As hFile
Print #hFile, ribbonXML
Close hFile

End Sub
```